# kaptDebugKotlin - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message) Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to update my libraries version in my old project and got these errors

[image]

I already match some of library versions from other project that built successfully, but still no impact. Also try to copied some of plugins from the error project to my other project, it works fine.

Here is my gradle settings :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.41"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    namespace "com.apps.test"
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apps.test"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "checkapps")
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/printer_library.jar')
    def nav_version = "2.5.3"
    def dealscreen_version = "1.0.6"
    def corutines_version = '1.6.1-native-mt'

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.41"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.41"

    /* hilt viewmodel extension*/
//    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$hilt_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"

    // Room Database
    def room_version = "2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // network
    def okhttp_version = '4.6.0'
    def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
    def moshi_version = "1.8.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"

    // okhttp
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"

    // moshi
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshi_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-adapters:$moshi_version"
    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshi_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit_version"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$corutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$corutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.21"

    //chart
    implementation 'com.github.AnyChart:AnyChart-Android:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

    //image
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    implementation 'io.coil-kt:coil:0.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:v0.0.4'

    // image loading and caching
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

    //qrcode
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'

    // deal screen
    implementation "com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:$dealscreen_version"
    implementation "com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:$dealscreen_version"

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    //loading gif
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0'

    // ocr
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:19.0.2'

    //recaptcha
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.1'

    //gif
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.23'

    // Printer
    implementation 'com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.3.0'

    // tesseract
    implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:9.0.0'
}
```

I tried to use `.\gradlew clean build`, invalidate cache, sync gradle project and still not working. Is that any error with the **printer** library (jar file) ? Or do I need to re-check my library versions properly ? But in other project, it works fine and can build it with no error above. In addition, I use gradle version `8.0`.

Comment: As you said, verifying all your library versions would be the best action you could take. But I'd try to update Kotlin Gradle Plugin version first to a higher version. It might be because AGP 8.0 embeds a newer version of Kotlin (see  the compatibility matrix for more: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#kotlin)